# Matplotlib multiple scatter plot picker

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I am trying to follow [this demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/pick_event_demo.html) on handling pick events on scatter plots. The demo works for a single scatter plot. However, when I add a second scatter plot, I only get indices of one of the plots upon clicking on the points. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

def pick_scatter_plot():
    # picking on a scatter plot (matplotlib.collections.RegularPolyCollection)

    x, y, c, s = rand(4, 2)

    def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print('onpick3 scatter:', ind, x[ind], y[ind])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #first scatter plot:
    ax.scatter(x, y, 100, c, marker='o', picker=True)
    #second scatted plot
    ax.scatter(x*2, y, 50, c, marker='s', picker=True)  
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pick_scatter_plot()
    plt.show()
```

The first set is plotted with the marker 'o', the second set is plotted with the marker 's' like this:

[image]

However, when I click on all four points, I only get indices of 0 and 1. This is the output when I click all 4 points one by one:

```
('onpick3 scatter:', array([1], dtype=int32), array([0.18243891]), array([0.30505569]))
('onpick3 scatter:', array([1], dtype=int32), array([0.18243891]), array([0.30505569]))
('onpick3 scatter:', array([0], dtype=int32), array([0.35977978]), array([0.66748979]))
('onpick3 scatter:', array([0], dtype=int32), array([0.35977978]), array([0.66748979]))
```

My question is how to access the indices of the points of both scatter plots properly? Combining all the data into a single scatter plot would not work for me because I have multiple sets I need to plot with different markers and `scatter` does not allow for a list of markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you have to identify first which is the scatter you are clicking on, and then you use that to get the point from the right array. I identified each scatter by their labels, then, if it is `_collection0` get the points from array `x`, `y`, if it is from `_collection1` get the points from x*2, y*2

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand

def pick_scatter_plot():
    # picking on a scatter plot (matplotlib.collections.RegularPolyCollection)

    x, y, c, s = rand(4, 2)

    def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        label = event.artist.get_label()
        if label == '_collection0':
            print('onpick3 scatter:', label, ind, x[ind], y[ind])
        elif label == '_collection1':
            print('onpick3 scatter:', label, ind, (x*2)[ind], (y*2)[ind])


    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    #first scatter plot:
    ax.scatter(x, y, 100, c, marker='o', picker=True)
    #second scatted plot
    ax.scatter(x*2, y, 50, c, marker='s', picker=True)  
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pick_scatter_plot()
    plt.show()
```

This is the output after clicking all four points:

```
onpick3 scatter: _collection0 [0] [0.56367835] [0.45595969]
onpick3 scatter: _collection0 [1] [0.71088259] [0.22692447]
onpick3 scatter: _collection1 [0] [1.12735669] [0.91191939]
onpick3 scatter: _collection1 [1] [1.42176517] [0.45384893]
```

You can see all the combinations:
collection 0: point 0, point 1;
collection 1: point 0, point 1

Comment: thank you! Are collections always numbered from 0 and up? Or is there a way to specify names for the collections? In a more complicated algorithm it could be hard to follow the order of the scatter plots so it may be safer to specify their names to track it easier afterwards.

Comment: oh, it looks like `event.artist.get_label()` actually returns the label specified by the `label=` parameter in the scatter plot if any is specified.